# Cannot download node-sass HTTP error 404 Not found --- Node Gyp error

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node-sass

I am  working on a project for an internship on Angular and after trying to install a few modules from NgPrime I m getting the following errors every time I run an `npm install` regarding:

1. node-sass(cannot download)
2. node-gyp

Here is what I get after running npm install:

```
> node-sass@4.10.0 install C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\flaviu.cristian\\Desktop\\BSS\\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.18.3 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe Error: not found: C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe". checking python launcher 
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe". guessing location 
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\flaviu.cristian\\Desktop\\BSS\\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\flaviu.cristian\Desktop\BSS\TrackGPS.BSS.Web\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @angular/core@7.2.16 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.8.26 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-snotify@4.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-snotify@4.3.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 1278 packages in 22.376s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 13 vulnerabilities (6 low, 4 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "TrackGPS.BSS",
  "version": "8.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=local",
    "build-local": "node --max-old-space-size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=local",
    "build-dev": "node --max-old-space-size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=dev",
    "build-test": "node --max-old-space-size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=test",
    "build-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.0.1",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "primeflex": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "1.0.0",
    "primeng": "7.1.3",
    "prismjs": "1.15.0",
    "quill": "1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-l10n": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^5.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.3.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  }
}
```

Initially after downloading the project and running for the first time npm install everything worked fine.I have tried to get back to my previous commit on git where everything was working but it did not solve my problem.

If there is any file that would might help you get a better understanding of the errors I will gladly post it

Comment: What is your Node Version? `node -v`

Comment: The Node Version is 12.18.3

Answer (score 10):

`v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node` - simply does not exist.

As far as I can tell - you can only use a certain `node-sass` version range with a specific Node.Js version.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimum-support

So in your case: When you are using Node 12 - you must update to `node-sass@4.12`

This *should* get rid of the errors.

This is explained in the repos FAQ:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#404s

Comment: Just to add for future reference, here is another [link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#404s) explaining the error and [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/) where you can download older node versions

Answer (score 2):

**NPM version is outdated.**

That is the reason that not find the dependency.

After searching all over the places finally I found the solution

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```