# NPM restore attempting to retrieve non-existent node-sass

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-sass

I'm trying to understand how NPM is coming up with this specific non-existent URL to retrieve node-sass.

My package.json includes:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "<=4.5.3",
    "request": "<=2.81.0",
    "shrinkwrap": "^0.4.0"
  },
```

From VS2019 I perform a restore on the package.json.  One of the first things it tries to install is node-sass, but it generates a request for a release asset that doesn't exist:

```
> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Dev\LegacyProject\Dev\LegacyProject.Web\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node": 
HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

This release exists, but in the assets of that release there is no asset with a "-72" for this release: win32-x64-***72***_binding.node:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3

**What does this "-72" specify in the asset naming convention?**
**Why would it be trying to install a non-existent release asset?  In other words, how does it come up with this specific URL?**

Comment: Per https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy 72 means Node 12, which v4.5.3 doesn't support (or doesn't provide a pre-compiled binary for, at least). If you want to continue using that version of `node-sass` you'll need to use Node 8 (which is out of LTS support per https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) or build it yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe THanks, if you post as answer I'll mark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot download node-sass HTTP error 404 Not found --- Node Gyp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263601/cannot-download-node-sass-http-error-404-not-found-node-gyp-error)

Comment: Sort of, they do state that package version does not support their node version.  But I think the explanation that "-72" part of the filename is generated from your local node version is a helpful piece of troubleshooting info that explains the seemingly nonsensical URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffixes like `-72` relate to the *Node version* for which that binary was built, per e.g. https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy:

| NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node 16 | 6.0+ | 93 |
| Node 15 | 5.0+ | 88 |
| Node 14 | 4.14+ | 83 |
| Node 13 | 4.13+, <5.0 | 79 |
| Node 12 | 4.12+ | 72 |
| Node 11 | 4.10+, <5.0 | 67 |
| Node 10 | 4.9+, <6.0 | 64 |
| Node 8 | 4.5.3+, <5.0 | 57 |
| Node <8 | <5.0 | <57 |

If it's trying to download `-72` you're presumably using Node 12, which doesn't have a pre-compiled binary for `node-sass@4.5.3`.

You can see more about this Node Module version on e.g. https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/, which says:

> `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` refers to the ABI (application binary interface)
> version number of Node.js, used to determine which versions of Node.js
> compiled C++ add-on binaries can be loaded in to without needing to be
> re-compiled. It used to be stored as hex value in earlier versions,
> but is now represented as an integer.