# Can't able to install the node-sass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, node-sass, sass-loader

I am using node version of `v16.2.0` and react version of `v17.0.2` , I can't able to install the node-sass to run the sass file. I tried to install the latest, but I can't. So please share your about that, it will be helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: `node-sass` only supports Node 16 from v6. Most likely you should be using Node 14 at the moment (that's what e.g. Create React App supports).

Comment: Relating to your point, I have only Node version as 16

Comment: Yes, we can see that. So you'll have to either upgrade `node-sass` (which will be tricky if that's a transitive dependency via `react-scripts` - presumably that's what you mean by *"I tried to install the latest, but I can't"* but a [mre] would help) or downgrade Node.

Comment: The latest version of `node-sass` is 6.0.0. If you mean you used _Node_ 14, please give a [mre] to illustrate the problem - what you're showing is an error with Node Module 93, which corresponds to Node 16 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793354/3001761).

Comment: I tried the latest version of node sass (version 14), but still it showing the same error

Comment: That's the same thing you just said, and it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: hey..thank you so much, I used the node-sass version 4, now I upgraded, thank you so much...:), have a happy life